# cache a httpmessage content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, memorycache

I would like to start caching some of the data in web API But I am getting some errors. I am using the HttpContent and storing it in cache using the `CacheHelper.SaveTocache`. On the next connection I am checking if it in cache then it’s creating a new `httpmessage` and setting the httpcontent for the new message but I am getting some errors ? How can I cache a `httpmessage`?

Errors when trying to get the data from cache

> Error: read ECONNRESET
> This site can’t be reached

Controller

```
    public class UserDataController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUser(string accessKey, string id)
        {
   
           DateTime cacheDuration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(cacheDurationTime);
           string cacheKey = String.Format("{0}_{1}", accessKey, id);
           if (CacheHelper.GetObjectFromCach(cacheKey) != null){
              var cacheContent = CacheHelper.GetFromCache<HttpContent>(cacheKey);

              var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
              response.Content = cacheContent;

              return ResponseMessage(response);

          else {
            var Results = User.UserFromId(id);

            CacheHelper.SaveTocache(cacheKey, Results.Content, cacheDuration);
            return ResponseMessage(Results);
       
          }
        }

    }
```

Helpers

```
   public static void SaveTocache(string cacheKey, object savedItem, DateTime absoluteExpiration)
   {
        MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, savedItem, absoluteExpiration);
   }


   public static T GetFromCache<T>(string cacheKey) where T : class
   {
        return MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] as T;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caching [`HttpContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-7.0) or [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=net-7.0) objects directly is generally not advisable, because of the internal state that these objects can maintain, including streams and headers which can be difficult to serialize or may be stateful in nature.

A "`read ECONNRESET`" or "`That site cannot be reached`" could indicate you are reusing an `HttpContent` object that has already been consumed, or an internal state that has been corrupted. When you store these complex objects in cache, they might retain some state that becomes invalid or non-reusable upon retrieval.

A more recommended approach is to cache the *raw data* that you want to send or have received. For instance, if you are returning JSON or XML data, consider caching that string representation instead of the entire `HttpContent` or `HttpResponseMessage` object.

```cs
public class UserDataController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(string accessKey, string id)
    {
        DateTime cacheDuration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(cacheDurationTime);
        string cacheKey = String.Format("{0}_{1}", accessKey, id);

        var cachedData = CacheHelper.GetFromCache<string>(cacheKey);
        
        if (cachedData != null)
        {
            var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(cachedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return ResponseMessage(response);
        }
        else
        {
            var Results = User.UserFromId(id);
            string rawData = Results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            
            CacheHelper.SaveTocache(cacheKey, rawData, cacheDuration);
            return ResponseMessage(Results);
        }
    }
}
```

That would make sure you are caching only the data that you need and minimizes the chances of running into issues due to object state.

---

> Is there a way to get the raw data from the httpcontent?

Yes, you should be able to extract the raw data from `HttpContent` by reading the content as a string, byte array, or stream. One of the most common ways is to read it as a string using the [`ReadAsStringAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=net-7.0). That is an asynchronous method, so you would typically use it with `await`. In a synchronous context, you can use `.Result` to get the value, but be cautious as this could lead to deadlocks in some situations.

```cs
HttpContent content = /* your HttpContent object */;
string rawData = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

(see below, next section, for more)

Or, in a synchronous context:

```cs
string rawData = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

If you want to read the content as a byte array:

```cs
byte[] rawData = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Or, to read it as a stream:

```cs
Stream rawData = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Once you have the raw data, you can cache it using your caching logic and reconstruct the `HttpContent` or `HttpResponseMessage` object when needed.

---

When reading the content of an `HttpContent` object asynchronously, you can use the `async` and `await` keywords to ensure that the operation is awaited, thus preventing the main execution thread from being blocked. If you are inside an `async` method, you can directly `await` the asynchronous methods.

```cs
public async Task<string> ReadContentAsync(HttpContent content)
{
    // Await the ReadAsStringAsync method and return the result
    string rawData = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return rawData;
}
```

You can then use this method within another `async` method like so:

```cs
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserAsync(string accessKey, string id)
{
    // other logic ...

    HttpResponseMessage Results = await User.UserFromIdAsync(id);
    string rawData = await ReadContentAsync(Results.Content);

    // Cache the rawData
    CacheHelper.SaveTocache(cacheKey, rawData, cacheDuration);

    // other logic ...
}
```

Note the `async` keyword added to the method definition and the `await` keyword before calling asynchronous methods. That ensures that the asynchronous operations are correctly awaited.

Comment: Is there a way to get the raw data from the httpcontent?

Comment: @Jefferson I have edited the answer to address your comment/question.